# Testing a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to create a Spring Boot test for a Controller-class.

The method I want to test is:

```
private String statusQueryToken;

@RequestMapping("/onCompletion")
public String whenSigningComplete(@RequestParam("status_query_token") String token){
    this.statusQueryToken = token;
```

I am unsure about how to test things in Spring Boot.

If I wanted to test that the field `statusQueryToken` has been initialized with the `@RequestParam("status_query_token")`, how would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: *"I am unsure about how to test things in Spring Boot."* - do you mean *before* or *after* reading [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Spring [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html)

So try something like this:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
mockMvc.perform(get("/onCompletion").param("status_query_token", "yourToken"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several way you can approach this. My preferred way to test with the real tomcat instance.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebIntegrationTest("server.port:0")
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(YourMainApplication.class)
    public class TestClass() {
        @Value("${local.server.port}")
        private int port;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public <T> T get(String path, Class<T> responseType, Object... pathVariables) {
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(path, responseType, pathVariables).getBody();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Using Spring's MockMvc is a better solution, see @SergheyBishyr answer, and mark that one as the accepted answer if you're convinced

Comment: As I said there are several approach to do this, but I prefer to test on real server instance rather than faking the request and response, but it all depends on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to test

**1. Using Maven**

```
$ mvn clean install
```

This will generate the jar file with spring boot embedded with tomcat by default

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

This will run you spring app

Now Spring is up and running

**2. Creating an executable jar (in absence on maven)**

```
$ java -jar target/myproject.0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar
```

"Same effect as above"

Now open the browser or soap ui or fiddler or postmaster to send request to the controller

ex: GET method
http://localhost:8080/myproject/onCompletion/hello

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

Comment: You're describing how to *run* an application, not how to *test* it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ItemFeedTest {

@InjectMocks
private PersonRepository personRepository;


@Autowired
@Mock
private PersonService personService;


@Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

@Test
    public void onSuccessTest() {
        //Write the Junit Test and mock the required Class
}

}
```