# How to test native queries in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, tdd, integration-testing

I am completely new in coding by following TDD approach. Now, I'm not sure whether every code needs test case, before it is written. How do I test native queries with if-else conditions?

I've researched some of the ways like following but didn't satisfy my question though:

[Testing a Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367588/testing-a-spring-boot-application)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=test+entitymanager

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=entitymanager+returned+null+in+testing

[JUnit test if else case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278040/junit-test-if-else-case)

```
@Transactional
public class ProfileRepositoryCustomImpl implements ProfileRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<ProfileMinimalResponseDTO> searchProfile(ProfileDTO profileDTO) {

        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(QueryCreator.createQueryToSearchProfile.apply(profileDTO));

        List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(list))
            throw new NoContentFoundException(NoRecordsFound.MESSAGE, NoRecordsFound.DEVELOPER_MESSAGE);

        return list.stream().map(
                ProfileUtils.convertObjectToProfileResponseDTO)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Character status;

    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "sub_department_id")
    private Long subDepartmentId;

}
```

```
public class QueryCreator {

    public static Function<ProfileDTO, String> createQueryToSearchProfile = (profileDTO -> {
        String query = "";

        query += " SELECT" +
                " p.id," +                          //[0]
                " p.name," +                        //[1]
                " p.status," +                      //[2]
                " p.department_id," +               //[3]
                " p.sub_department_id" +            //[4]
                " FROM" +
                " profile p" +
                " WHERE p.id!=0";

        if (!Objects.isNull(profileDTO)) {
            if (!Objects.isNull(profileDTO.getName()))
                query += " AND p.name='" + profileDTO.getName() + "'";

            if (!Objects.isNull(profileDTO.getDepartmentId()))
                query += " AND p.department_id=" + profileDTO.getDepartmentId();

            if (!Objects.isNull(profileDTO.getSubDepartmentId()))
                query += " AND p.sub_department_id=" + profileDTO.getDepartmentId();
        }

        return query;
    });

}
```

```
 public static Function<Object[], ProfileMinimalResponseDTO> convertObjectToProfileResponseDTO = (objects) -> {

        final Integer ID = 0;
        final Integer NAME = 1;
        final Integer STATUS = 2;
        final Integer DEPARTMENT_ID = 3;
        final Integer SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID = 4;

        return ProfileMinimalResponseDTO.builder()
                .id(Long.parseLong(objects[ID].toString()))
                .name(objects[NAME].toString())
                .status(objects[STATUS].toString().charAt(0))
                .departmentId(Long.parseLong(objects[DEPARTMENT_ID].toString()))
                .subDepartmentId(Long.parseLong(objects[SUB_DEPARTMENT_ID].toString()))
                .build();
    };
```

I am expecting answers on how to write test case for above scenerio. Also, any references to learning TDD would be very kind and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

regarding references for learning TDD I would definitely recommend a classic book, Kent Beck's "TDD by example":
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Test-Driven-Development-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321146530

One approach would be to use some in-memory database (H2 being a natural choice in case of Spring Boot). You could then create `schema.sql` and `data.sql` scripts to insert specific data to test your corner cases.

Another option is to use Mockito to mock `EntityManager` and `Query` objects. You then don't need to create SQL with inserts and 'create tables', but you prepare a set of objects manually which will be returned by these mocks.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this a bit.